# Getting the recent article through Lucene.Net

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6, lucene

I want to get the recent article based on one field: **pubdate**. I have this approach for now:

```
     private void GetLastIndexId()
        {
            string indexLocation = @"C:\\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebsite\Data\indexes\newsArticle";
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexLocation);
            IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(dir);
            IndexSearcher indexSearch = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("id", analyzer);

            Query query = qp.Parse("pubdate: [2012-01-01T00:00:000-00:00 3012-01-01T00:00:000-00:00]");
            Hits hits = indexSearch.Search(query);
 List<Document> myHits = new List<Document>();
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
              {
                 if (i == hits.Length() - 1)
                   {
                     Document doc = hits.Doc(i);
                     lastPubDate = doc.GetValues("pubdate").First();
                   }
              }

        }
```

**EDIT:** I did this in which I am getting the length-1 item from the content items. This is kind of a hack because if the folder structure is changed then this could would fail.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the IndexSearcher.Search overload accepting a sort argument?

```
var sortField = new SortField("pubdate", SortField.STRING, /*reverse*/ true);
var hits = searcher.Search(query, /*filter*/ null, /*count*/ 1, new Sort(sortField));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
  var sortField = new SortField("pubdate", SortField.STRING, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length(); i++)
        {
            Document doc = hits.Doc(i);
            string getDate = doc.GetValues("pubdate").First();

            if (string.Compare(getDate, lastPubDate) > 0)
            {
                lastPubDate = doc.GetValues("pubdate").First();
            }
        }
```